# extract item from a multi dimensional array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am using jQuery with jqgrid and I wanted to use few value from the edit results.  The result of the edit is a multidimensional array.  For some reason I can only alert up to the second child, the result goes `undefined` if i go any further.

The main array variable is `postdata` and if i have to iterate this using jQuery's `.each()`  function, I get these:

(item : value) format.  the number is for the order of appearance

```
1 readyState : 4

2 setRequestHeader : function({....}) 
..
..
..
21 responseText : Array (
        [id] => 364
        [oper] => edit
        [note] => editing
        [client] => raha
   )
```

My intention is to get the value of `id` but if i have to alert the array outside the `.each()` function using this:

```
alert(postdata['responseText']['id'])
```

The alert result is `undefined`. If I removed the `['id']`, it shows the entire `responseText` array (same with number 21).

How do I accomplish this task?
many thanks.

**SOLVED!**
Thanks to @Felix for the idea and to @Jasper for suggesting about the `console.log`.

The result of the jqGrid `responseText` is in double quotes, which makes it a string.  I managed to solve this using the `.split()` function, two splits to be exact.  First splitting it by `'\n'` and then by `'=>'`.  I finally got what I wanted.

Thanks all

Comment: Could you check the type of `postdata['responseText']`? I suspect it is a string, as that Array stuff looks like what php's print_r outputs when given an array.

Comment: i ran a console.log(postdata), as suggested by @Jasper, and the result is exactly the same as above.

Comment: I think you're right in saying that it's a string because it shows in double qoutation in firebug console.  Is it possible to select an item from this? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can log the `postdata` variable and post the whole variable it would be much easier to give you advice (`console.log(postdata);`). That being said perhaps `responseText` is an array of objects in which case you would need to access its data like this:

```
alert(postdata['responseText'][0]['id']);
```

Comment: the result of the `console.log(postdata)` is the same, apart from a double qoute that holds the Array for responseText.

The alert renders undefined.